# How to have react-datepicker update Formik nested object

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, formik, react-datepicker

So I set up datepicker within my form like so

```
<FieldArray
  name="config"
  render={(arrayHelpers) => (
   <div>
     {values.config.map((config, index) => (
       <div key={index}>

...

<DatePicker
 name={`config.${index}.date`}
 type="date"
 value={values.date}
 className={
 "form-control" +
 (errors.date&& touched.date
 ? " is-invalid"
 : "")
 }
 onChange={(e) =>
  setFieldValue("date", e)
}
/>
```

The data is added to the state but as an additional field instead of updating the initial state within formik. It updates likes this.

```
{"domain_url":"","schema_name":"","name":"","config":[{"first":"","last":"","email":"","date":""}],"date":"2020-06-10T04:00:00.000Z"}
```

I would appreciate any ideas.

below is a new edit of the majority of the code.
the datepicker is not displaying the date within the form field but it is updating the state correctly, now I just need it to display correctly within the form and format the date to drop the string at the end

```
static propTypes = {
    addTenant: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  onSubmit = (values) => {
    values.preventDefault();

    this.props.addTenant(values);
  };

  render() {
    const {
      domain_url,
      schema_name,
      name,
      config,
    } = this.state;

    const TenantSchema = Yup.object().shape({
      domain_url: Yup.string()
        .max(255, "Must be shorter than 255 characters")
        .required("Client URL header is required"),
      schema_name: Yup.string()
        .max(255, "Must be shorter than 255 characters")
        .required("Client db name is required"),
      name: Yup.string()
        .max(255, "Must be shorter than 255 characters")
        .required("Client name is required"),
    });
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            domain_url: "",
            schema_name: "",
            client_name: "",
            config: [
              {
                date: "",
                Tenant_description: "",
              },
            ],
          }}
          // validationSchema={TenantSchema} this is commented off because it breaks         
         submittions
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
            setSubmitting(true);
            values.domain_url = values.domain_url + ".localhost";
            setTimeout(() => {
              alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
              resetForm();
              setSubmitting(false);
            }, 100);
          }}


        >
          {({
            values,
            errors,
            status,
            touched,
            handleBlur,
            handleChange,
            isSubmitting,
            setFieldValue,
            handleSubmit,
            props,
          }) => (
            <FormGroup>
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <legend>
                  <strong>Create</strong> Tenant
                </legend>
                <FormGroup row>
                  <Label for="normal-field" md={4} className="text-md-right">
                    Show URL
                  </Label>
                  <Col md={7}>
                    <InputGroup>
                      <Field
                        id="appended-input"
                        name="domain_url"
                        type="text"
                        value={values.domain_url}
                        className={
                          "form-control" +
                          (errors.domain_url && touched.domain_url
                            ? " is-invalid"
                            : "")
                        }
                      />
                      <ErrorMessage
                        name="domain_url"
                        component="div"
                        className="invalid-feedback"
                      />
                      <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
                        .localhost
                      </InputGroupAddon>
                    </InputGroup>
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                  <Label for="normal-field" md={4} className="text-md-right">
                    Database Name
                  </Label>
                  <Col md={7}>
                    <Field
                      name="schema_name"
                      type="text"
                      className={
                        "form-control" +
                        (errors.schema_name && touched.schema_name
                          ? " is-invalid"
                          : "")
                      }
                    />
                    <ErrorMessage
                      name="schema_name"
                      component="div"
                      className="invalid-feedback"
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                  <Label for="normal-field" md={4} className="text-md-right">
                    Name
                  </Label>
                  <Col md={7}>
                    <Field
                      name="name"
                      type="text"
                      className={
                        "form-control" +
                        (errors.name && touched.name
                          ? " is-invalid"
                          : "")
                      }
                    />
                    <ErrorMessage
                      name="name"
                      component="div"
                      className="invalid-feedback"
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FieldArray
                  name="config"
                  render={(arrayHelpers) => (
                    <div>
                      {values.config.map((config, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                           <FormGroup row>
                            <Label
                              md={4}
                              className="text-md-right"
                              for="mask-date"
                            >
                              Tenant Description
                            </Label>
                            <Col md={7}>
                              <TextareaAutosize
                                rows={3}
                                name={`config.${index}.tenant_description`}
                                id="elastic-textarea"
                                type="text"
                                onReset={values.event_description}
                                placeholder="Quick description of tenant"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                value={values.tenant_description}
                                onBlur={handleBlur}
                                className={
                                  `form-control ${s.autogrow} transition-height` +
                                  (errors.tenant_description &&
                                  touched.tenant_description
                                    ? " is-invalid"
                                    : "")
                                }
                              />
                              <ErrorMessage
                                name="tenant_description"
                                component="div"
                                className="invalid-feedback"
                              />
                            </Col>
                          </FormGroup>
                          <FormGroup row>
                            <Label
                              for="normal-field"
                              md={4}
                              className="text-md-right"
                            >
                              Date
                            </Label>
                            <Col md={7}>
                              <DatePicker    
                               name={`config[${index}]['date']`}
                               selected={getIn(values, `config[${index}] 
                                ['date']`) || ''}
                               value={getIn(values, `config[${index}] 
                                ['date']`) || ''}
                               onChange={(e) =>
                               setFieldValue(`config[${index}]['date']`, e);
                               }   
                               />
                              />
                              <ErrorMessage
                                name="date"
                                component="div"
                                className="invalid-feedback"
                              />
                            </Col>
                          </FormGroup>

                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  )}
                />
                <div className="form-group">
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                    className="btn btn-primary mr-2"
                  >
                    Save Tenant
                  </button>
                  <button type="reset" className="btn btn-secondary">
                    Reset
                  </button>
                </div>
              </Form>

              <Col md={7}>{JSON.stringify(values)}</Col>
            </FormGroup>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { addTenant })(TenantForm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change your name,value and onChange as following**

```
  import { FieldArray, getIn } from 'formik'; 

    <DatePicker    
         name={`config[${index}]['date']`}
         selected={getIn(values, `config[${index}]['date']`) || ''}
         value={getIn(values, `config[${index}]['date']`) || ''}
         onChange={(e) =>
         setFieldValue(`config[${index}]['date']`, e);
        }   
     />
```

Comment: what is the getI() function, its not defined, where am I pulling it from?

Comment: i have added import in my answer. It must be imported from formik.

Comment: it worked! but it now does not display the date selected within the input field. I didn't know it was a formik function. thank you. I also added the full code to the other question of mine you answered, the appended input one.

Comment: that didnt work i also tried to add dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"so that T04:00:00.000Z wouldn't trail behind it but no luck

Comment: It should have worked with selected property. I just tried here  https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-z3qmm?file=/index.js   Can you confirm getIn(values, `config[${index}]['date']`) is giving you the date?

Comment: yes getin values are giving me the date, but I think that since I'm not passing props the same way as your example its not displaying correctly hence why the selected date doesn't appear within the inputbox

Comment: Is there any error throwing? Try parsing by ' new Date' like this  selected={new Date(getIn(values, `config[${index}]['date']`))}

Comment: Line 283:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "]"

  281 |                                 name={`config[${index}]['event_start']`}
  282 |                                 placeholder="Enter date"
> 283 |                                 selected={new Date(getIn(values, config[${ index }]['date']))}

Comment: I added the full code above so you can check it out